# Is there a way to make code completion in Netbeans work automatically

Tags: java, netbeans

While coding java in Netbeans, I have to keep pressing CTRL + space to show code completion.
Is there any possible way or plugin to make Netbeans show code completion as I type without resulting to CTRL + space.

Most of the modern IDE's have this option working fine, I wonder why in Netbeans it is like that, despite that Netbeans is a good IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/working_nbeans.htm#NBDAG2927)

Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Completion

Then check "Auto Popup Completion Window"

[image]

You can also customize the options for Java there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(NB 7.4) You should go to Tools > Options > Code Completion and select Language: Java and tick `Auto Popup on Typing ...`.