# Variable Code Completion in Netbeans without Ctrl+Space

Tags: c++, netbeans, ide, editor

Is it possible to enable auto code completion for **variables** in Netbeans?
I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340928/is-there-a-way-to-make-code-completion-in-netbeans-work-automatically), but it doesn't work on variables (correct me if I'm wrong).

This is my current code completion setting:
[image: a screenshot]

Comment: It is possible, but you are on the wrong screen. Select "C/C++" from that "Language" droplist in your screen shot, then follow the instructions in the following SO answer which works:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871967/netbeans-c-auto-popup-code-completion/33748393#33748393

Comment: @skomisa I tried that but it still didn't work

Comment: Strange. I've posted an answer to give greater details. If it's still not working for you after reviewing my answer and verifying your settings please provide more details of the failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

- In NetBeans select **Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Completion tab -> Language: C/C++**
- As given [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871967/netbeans-c-auto-popup-code-completion/33748393#33748393), set the content of the **Auto Popup Triggers...** field to contain the following string:

**.;->;.*;->*;::;new ; ;a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;r;s;t;u;v;w;x;y;z;**

- Click the **Apply** button, then click **OK**.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: OptionsScreen]

The change should be immediately effective. After doing that you can type the first letter of any variable in your C++ source code and eligible variables should be listed in the prompt which automatically appears.

The screen shot below is a contrived example where there are several variables starting with 's'. All I did was type the letter 's' and the prompt appeared instantly, listing all of the local and global variables starting with 's':

[image: CodeCompletionPrompt]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer (and sorry for responding so late)! I tried that and it works. I'm still not sure why it didn't work when I tried it before. But still, thanks again.